# Configuration to rebuild/reload angular application on saving changes

Tags: angular, configuration, save, reload, rebuild

The `--watch` and `--live-reload` works on change detection, and they are usable with `serve` command. But is there any configuration so that rebuild and reload happens *only* when I save my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem comes from your IDE. `--watch` rebuild the app when some file change, so if your IDE save when the focus change (Like Jetbrains IDE Collections such WebStorm), your app is rebuilt.

Change that option in your IDE and everything must work like you want :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just discovered my VSCode is not respecting the `"files.autoSave": "off"` setting.

Comment: Disabling auto-save so you can prevent some automatic rebuilds seems like using a nuclear warhead to prune the bushes... some fallout is likely.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngOnChanges()` hook with your function.